# How long does it take for an animal to grow up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Version 1.0 of Minecraft added baby animals and breeding.  So now I've begun animal husbandry, and I'm off to a good start, I'm just growing impatient with a few of them.  Specifically, *they won't grow up*.

How long will it take my calves, chicks, and piglets to grow up into fully [murder](/questions/tagged/murder)-able cows, chickens and pigs?

On a related note, how long do I have to wait after breeding a pair of animals before I can breed them again?

Comment: If I had to guess they probably have to be in a loaded chunk, so maybe 30 mins afk in a safe spot near them would be your best bet.

Comment: @Maxorq The reason I haven't so far is because my own experience contradicts it.

Comment: @JohntheGreen maybe they need those 20 minutes, but chunk have to be active or something?

Comment: Comment by anonymous: "Found that about every 5 minutes at least for chickens, you can feed them and breed. Haven't found out what the time is for full maturity"

Comment: For an explained answer check [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113216/how-often-can-animals-breed/113224#113224) post.

Answer (score 12):

From the wiki [Breeding/Baby animals](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding#Baby_animals)

> Baby animals grow into full sized animals after twenty minutes, one day in game time.

Comment: Ok, then why haven't my calves grown up after 2 full game days?

Comment: I.e. I would like a personally verified answer.

Comment: according to this post: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/786164-my-baby-animals-wont-grow/ it should take from 1 to 6 minecraft days maximum, let's ask notch :D

Comment: Notch is an acceptably verified answer! :D

Comment: Yeah , around 20 minutes, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

20 minutes, or one game day. So from dawn until the next dawn (unless you sleep though the night in which case it will be two full daytimes). You can breed an animal once per game day.

Comment: it akes about 5 minutes till you can breed animals again I belive

Answer (score 0):

Update as of release 1.8: Baby animals grow into full sized animals after twenty minutes (one game day, beds notwithstanding). **Their growth can slowly be accelerated using the animal's breeding item, where each use takes 10% off the remaining time to grow up.** There are a few variations:

Sheep can grow faster if they eat grass.
For dogs (tamed wolves), the puppy does not gain its full health automatically (even when it grows to full size), but must be fed to increase its HP.
Foals (baby horses) can be fed to speed their growth.